# how to reset dropdown field in form created using spring form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, spring-mvc

I have a situation like this.

```
    <form:select path="Addresses[1].stateId" data-validate='""'>
         <form:option value="0" > </form:option>
         <form:options items="${statesList}" itemLabel="value" itemValue="key" />
    </form:select>
```

On click of a text , I need to reset this field, i.e point it to value 0.

I used

```
    document.getElementById("Addresses1.stateId").selectedIndex = 0
```

It changes the backend value but not the display . Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Assign value to the select:

```
document.getElementById("Addresses1.stateId").value = 0
```

Comment: value changes now . but the UI remains same

Comment: if I understand properly from Spring documentation, `path` attribute of a select taf converts into `name` HTML attribute, not `id`. Check your generated HTML for correct `name` attribute and try to do something like this: `document.getElementsByName("Addresses1.stateId")[0].value = 0;`

Comment: am sorry, path adds both name and id. name is the same thing "Addresses[1].stateId" and id is without the brackets "Addresses1.stateId" .

Comment: Ok and what about: `document.getElementById("Addresses1.stateId").options[0].selected = 'selected';`